# function for showing unique cells

Tags: excel, vba

VBA function which deletes duplicates and writes with comma

I need a formula (function) which will have two arguments:
1.range (will be selected)
2.separator character between duplicates.
Example I have in a range some codes of products 0001, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0015, 0020 in different cells. I want to get 0001, 0015, 0020 using formula.

What I have written:

```
Function UNIQUE_NUMBER(RangeD As Range, SepCharacter As String)
Dim UNIQUE As String
On Error GoTo msg
For Each cell In RangeD
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
    If Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column) = "" Then Resume Next
    r = cell.Row
    C = cell.Column
    a_length = Len(a)
    a = a & SepCharacter & Cells(r, C)


        If WorksheetFunction.Search(Cells(r, C) & SepCharacter, a, a_length + 1) > 1 And Cells(r, C) <> "" Then
        a = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(a, Cells(r, C) & SepCharacter, "", 1)

        End If
End If

Next cell
SepCharacter2 = SepCharacter & SepCharacter
UNIQUE = Mid(a, Len(SepCharacter) + 1, Len(a))
UNIQUE_NUMBER = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(UNIQUE, SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, ""), SepCharacter2, "")
Exit Function
msg:
Resume Next
End Function
```

And it sometimes work correctly (somehow), but sometimes doesn’t
What do you offer?

Comment: You might put "stop" as the first command and step (F8) through a case where it doesn't work to see where it fails.

Comment: this is not sub, so there is a problem. Or may be you have any suggestions to do it other way?

Comment: You can call it from a sub, instead of from a cell, so you can debug it.  Commenting out the error handler would help.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was solved

```
Function UNIQUE_WELDER(RangeD As Range, sepChar As String)

'we will gather all unique values into VAL1
VAL1 = ""
For Each cell In RangeD

'if value is added into VAL1 we will not add again
'and using replace function for deleting spaces
qty = InStr(VAL1, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(cell, " ", ""), " ", ""), " ", ""), " ", ""), " ", ""), " ", ""))
If qty > 0 Then VAL1 = VAL1 Else VAL1 = Replace(VAL1 & sepChar & cell, sepChar & sepChar, sepChar)
Next cell
'deleting first symbol
VAL2 = Mid(VAL1, Len(sepChar) + 1, 1000)
UNIQUE_WELDER = VAL2
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,

- your product codes are in a range of cells, with one code per cell
- your output should be in a single cell, as a `sepChar` separated cell.

  - Since you show your output with `comma-space` as the separator, I put that as the default separator in the code.

If you have Excel O365, you can do this with a worksheet formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(myRange))
```

If not, a VBA routine is probably easiest:

To extract unique values from a list, I would suggest using a Dictionary or Collection object, although there are other, efficient methods.

In the code below, I demonstrate the Collection object, as it is also present in Excel for MAC.

```
Option Explicit
Function vbaUNIQUE(rg As Range, Optional sep As String = ", ") As String
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long, s As String

Set col = New Collection

'Collection object will return an error if we try
' to add a duplicate key.  Therefore the `OnError`
' statement will skip over any duplicates
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In rg
    If Not c.Value = "" Then col.Add Item:=c.Value, Key:=CStr(c.Value)
Next c
On Error GoTo 0

'create output string
For i = 1 To col.Count
    s = s & sep & col(i)
Next i

vbaUNIQUE = Mid(s, Len(sep) + 1)

End Function
```

[image]